# DENWER - The requested URL ... was not found on this server

Tags: denwer

Я запускаю сервер для работы с `PHP` на компьютере без интернета.
В интернете нашёл программу виртуального сервера - `Denwer`. С установкой проблем не было. Когда запустил, почему-то ничего не работало.
Потом кое-где поменял настройки, загрузил все свои PHP-файлы, и всё стало работать. Версия PHP у меня 5.3.13.
Программировал вчера около 3 часов до вечера, затем корректно выключил `Denwer` и компьютер. Сегодня утром включаю компьютер, запускаю `Denwer`, открываю `http://localhost` - пишет "It works!". Открываю файл, с которым вчера работал `http://localhost/index.php`, пишет `NOT FOUND - The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.`.
Несколько раз пробовал сервер перезапустить, перезагружал компьютер, но безрезультатно. Зашёл в интернет и попытался найти решение этой проблемы, встречал эту проблему на форумах, но она там так и оставалась не решённой.
Вот уже прошло полдня, перепробовал всё возможное, что приходило мне в голову, но опять же безрезультатно. Помогите мне, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему.
Я очень надеюсь, что на этом форуме найдутся люди, которые возможно сталкивались с этой проблемой и решали её, или просто знают, что необходимо сделать.

Comment: сервер натужно пытается вам сообщить, что файла index.php не существует на предполагаемом месте. Перезагрузка не поможет.

Comment: Существует! Я всё проверял. Я пытаюсь натужно его загрузить.

Comment: @Никита___, значит сервер предполагает его существование в другом месте. Насколько помню, денверу приходилось поднимать виртуальный диск, чтобы раздавать файлы.

Comment: А с чего он решил? Вчера же всё работало. Я вроде не менял никаких настроек. И файлы не удалял никакие. Очень странно.

Comment: У меня всё настроено вроде как правильно. Виртуальный диск у меня W:\, и он работает, всё в порядке. Просто серверок чёт поттупивает. 

Ну так что делать то? Мне переустанавливать Denwer придётся, да?

Может проблема в Apache 2.2.22?

Comment: а где конкретно лежит у вас этот index.php? Обычно требуется что-то типа F:\WebServers\home\phptest\www, и тогда будет запускатся по адресу phptest или phptest/index.php. Если просто закинуть в папку phptest напрямую, то работать не будет

Comment: Вчера переустановил - всё заработало!!! А сегодня включаю компьютер - опять эта ребедень!

Comment: @Никита___, выкиньте денвер, поставьте что-нибудь посовременней, openserver тот же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Необходимо выполнить следующие действия:

1. Открыть "Диспетчер процессов".
2. Найти там два одинаковых процесса "httpd.exe".
3. Завершить их.
4. Выключить денвер (НЕ перезагрузить!).
5. Включить денвер.
6. Если проблема не устранена, просто перезагрузите компьютер и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно сначала установить Денвер! По-моему, ты удалил некоторые данные!